# Render Polymer elements

Tags: polymer

i have installed the Polymer with Bower, but i can't render the html. I don't know whats is need... I required Python or other server to render the elementes? Im think in use this on Rails project.

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-elements/paper-elements.html">
  <link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-tabs/paper-tabs.html">
</head>
<body>
  <paper-tabs selected="0">
  <paper-tab>TAB 1</paper-tab>
  <paper-tab>TAB 2</paper-tab>
  <paper-tab>TAB 3</paper-tab>
</paper-tabs>

</body>
</html>
```

Screenshot:
[image]

Google Chrome console don't show any error, it's clean.

Answer (score 3):

It doesnt require python or any backend for that matter. Polymer is a javascript utility whose purpose is to "fill in" gaps in a browser's implementation of the web components standard. You just need to make sure that  all the necessary Js Files are included.

Specifically you need to include the platform.js file `<script src="{{Your PATH}}/platform.js"></script>`

Comment: Yes, the Polymer needs the file platform.js, but this file makes requests and CORS block this action. I start a webserv in my computer because this.

Comment: This is a limitation of the html5 import specifications. You will have to enable CORS on the specific files on your server or you will need to put your html documents on the same server.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify platform.js file for polyfill support. It is a must. Check the docs for a better understanding.

http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/start/getting-the-code.html

Polymer has good documentation.